# call waiting notification

Tags: alerts, call-waiting

Generally I get alert when I am in call . But I don't get any notification when the receiver is in call . How can I get notification or alert if my receiver is on a call ?

My phone is samsung gti5500
android version : 2.3.4

Comment: With "receiver" you mean the other party you are calling? That won't be possible unless the carrier supports it, I guess. With the very same phone I used at home, when calling a person here I always get the "free" sign if the other side has call-waiting activated -- while e.g. in Israel I get a "call waiting" signal (free="long,long,long", busy="short,short,short", call-waiting="long-short-long" tone). So it most likely has nothing to do with the phone, but rather the carrier. (Nothing proven, just a good-guess)

Comment: Yes I meant the other party . But it is possible , it is possible in every phone I have used so far . except in android phone .

Comment: Sure it is, I fully believe you -- but the carrier must support that feature. How shall the phone detect the fact if the carrier "hides" it? Are you sure the carrier you are currently using does support it (have you e.g. tried with another phone in parallel, or asked the support)? It might even be needed to be explicitly enabled for your "number" (i.e. your SIM).

Comment: Yes , my carrier supports this. I have this feature in every phone I have used so far , except my android . 
Can you suggest me an app ?

Comment: As no carrier supports it here, this is outside of my expertise. But now that we've clarified the backgrounds, somebody else might be able to help you out. It might be a good idea if you'd update your question to include the facts we've collected in the comments so far (that your carrier does support it, you've checked with other devices in the same are and it works). The solution should not be restricted to "an app", it could very well be some special setting you simply did not discover yet :)